# Adding table to tabular condenses table

Tags: tables

perhaps this is a basic question but I could not find an answer yet. Whenever I embed a table created with tabular into the table environment to add a caption, the new table is condensed. Is there a simple way to avoid this?

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
aaa & bbb \\
ccc & ddd
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \hline
     aaa & bbb \\
     ccc & ddd
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: that is not the default behaviour so it is due to code you have not shown. Please _always_ include a small but complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: having said that you are probably (or possibly) using the `setspace` or equivalent package that is double spacing the body of a document but single spacing tables.